# Cannot load QGIS Processing Plugin due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

Tags: qgis-3

Python error: Couldn't load plugin 'processing' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method See message log (Python Error) for more details.

I've tried redownloading QGIS multiple times, but I am unfamiliar with python so I do not know where the error here is.

I'm using QGIS 3.16.0, but the error still occurred when I downloaded 3.10.0

Couldn't load plugin 'processing' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 334, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 50, in classFactory
    from processing.ProcessingPlugin import ProcessingPlugin
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\ProcessingPlugin.py", line 47, in 
    from processing.gui.HistoryDialog import HistoryDialog
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\HistoryDialog.py", line 33, in 
    from processing.gui import TestTools
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\TestTools.py", line 34, in 
    from numpy import nan_to_num
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\Sophia Weng\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in 
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\Sophia Weng\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in 
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Check this thread: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31169